# Входят ли обувь и шляпа в группу галантерейных товаров?

Tags: семантика

Можно ли отнести обувь и шляпы к галантерейным товарам?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, их традиционно не включают в галантерею.

Comment: А платки и сумки?